# how to keep timer.shcedule() running when changing system time

Tags: java, android, timer, timertask

Recently, I am using android service to start a new timer and run a timerTask to do something.
The code is like this below:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new RetrieveTask(), 300000);

private class RetrieveTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //do something
        timer.schedule(new RetrieveTask(), 300000);
    }
}
```

It works well, but if I change the system time to an earlier time than the current system time it does not work. I went through the java API doc and know the reason.

How do I do if I want to keep it running even if I change the system time?

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already get solution. use receive to receive time change intent and restart this timer.